# Google Chrome not redirecting to VScode after authorizing with Github

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

The application “Google Chrome” does not have permission to open “vscode://vscode.github-authentication/did-authenticate?windowid=3&code=xxxxxxxxx&state=xxxxx-xxx-xx-xx-xx.”

macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Tried copy pasting the code in the address bar, did not work.
Also tried with "Github Pull Requests and Issues" installed on VScode, still did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure your VSCode application is not placed on ~/Downloads or ~/Documents folder. Move it to /Applications directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error, try entering vscode from the terminal first.

If you still get an error while entering from the terminal, "shell-command-install-with-comment" in vscode

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I updated my Chrome browser (for MacOS) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Updated VS Code to the latest version of VS Code (1.66+)

```
"We've made some updates to our authentication process for VS Code and GitHub."
```

and then updating Chrome as well fixed the issue.

Thanks