# Unable to authenticate github copilot in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, github, github-copilot

I am struggling with github copilot extension. Every time, I try to sign-in into github from my code, I get an error to update the vscode to something newer then 1.66.

Here is the exact error message in my browser (I get redirected from vscode to the web browser):

```
Please upgrade VS Code

We've made some updates to our authentication process for VS Code and GitHub. Please upgrade to the latest release of VS Code (1.66+) or download from here.
```

However my vscode version is 1.85.1

```
1.85.1
0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2
x64
```

I am using Linux, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to be more specific.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: nit: latest VS Code is 1.85.2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72237374/11107541 do you need to update chrome?

Comment: @starball I`ve seen this issue, I tried both firefox and google chrome, I keep both browsers up to date. Not sure if they are the latest version available since I use "Software updater" in Ubuntu to update those, but I update them on regular base.